# uwsgi only sending stdout logs to GCP in Kubernetes Engine

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, logging, uwsgi

I have a django application for which I want to send logs to GCP.

Locally, everything works fine using django dev server and Cloud Logging for Python. I see the logs on my GCP dashboard with the right level, I can also see the json structured logs when I use them.
It also works well when I'm using gunicorn in a local docker instead of the django dev server.

However, as soon as I'm using uwsgi locally, I can't find any trace of my logs in the GCP dashboard. When I deploy my docker image in Kubernetes Engine, all the logs are only displayed as info and they are not json structured anymore. I noticed that the logger name is `stdout` in my log explorer.

I'm supposing that somehow uwsgi don't use my python logging config and only logs to `stdout` that is automatically sent as info by some internal gcp process.

Here's my `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=xxx
module=xxx
http = 0.0.0.0:8080

vacuum = true
enable-threads = true
listen = 128
# socket-timeout, http-timeout and harakiri are in s
socket-timeout = 180
http-timeout = 180
harakiri = 180
harakiri-verbose = true
py-autoreload = false
processes = 4
memory-report = false
master = true
master-fifo = /tmp/master-fifo
post-buffering = 65536
buffer-size = 65535
max-requests = 1500
max-requests-delta = 100
max-worker-lifetime = 3600
hook-accepting1-once = write:/tmp/bkm.ready ok

# Logging configuration
# Disable request logging. It's done from the application
disable-logging = true

log-master = false
# this will only prefix system logs
log-prefix = [uWSGI]
```

and my logging configuration

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(name)s [%(module)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] > %(message)s',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s > %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console_simple': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'console_verbose': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'slack': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'api.project.logger.SlackHandler',
        },
        'stackdriver_logging': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'client': logging_v2.Client(),
            'labels': {'env': ENV_LABEL},
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'api': {
            'handlers': [
                # 'console_simple',
                'console_verbose',
                'stackdriver_logging',
                'slack',
            ],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console_verbose'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

I've tried different configuration of uwsgi (`log-master`, `log-encoder`...) but without any luck. I can correctly see my logs when I use gunicorn that's why I suspect uwsgi to be the cause but I'd like to avoid changing my wsgi server if possible.

I'm using a json service key and the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to manage my gcp credentials.